# A Short But Fun Riley

Tags: riddle, word

This suddenly popped into my head

> My Prefix is totally irreplaceable
>
> Even if it is, I wouldn't want to
>
> My Infix will definitely be fragile
>
> That is, if you add a letter to it
>
> My Suffix is what many people hate
>
> But it also lives in many of us
>
> My Whole is what many may enjoy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is It-

> Lego

Prefix-

> Leg, a vital organ. no one wants to lose it.

Infix-

> eg, add a g and becomes egg, very fragile

Suffix-

> Ego, not liked by people, but still most of us have it.

Finally-

> many people specially kids love playing with Lego.

Comment: Correct answer. Will accept tomorrow 'kay?

Comment: okay, BTW, did you by any chance saw my riddle before posting, :P the suffix was already in my head for the one i posted, just went from there and found the rest.. Fun one indeed.. cheers

Comment: Really? Haven't visited ur post lol :D